# Python Megawidgets tab widths

Tags: python, tkinter

How to I change the default width of the tabs on a notebook page?

```
import tkinter  #widget library ships with Python 
import Pmw      #allows access to update tkinter widgets

class TextBookGUI:
    # class constructor
    # populates each note book page
    def __init__(self, master):

        #place hash tables here

        """
         Create 5 pages on using Pmw notebook widget.
         Documenation for notebook:
         http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/NoteBook.html
        """

        self.nb = Pmw.NoteBook(master)
        Pmw.Color.changecolor(self.nb.component('hull'), background='blue')



        self.HomeTab = self.nb.add("Welcome")
        self.nb.tab('Welcome').focus_set()

        self.StudentTab = self.nb.add("Students")
        self.BookTab = self.nb.add("Books")
        self.LoanTab = self.nb.add("Loans")
        self.HelpTab = self.nb.add("Help")
        self.nb.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.nb.setnaturalsize()

        #format the house style of tabs: yellow bg and blue text   
        self.nb.component('Welcome-tab').configure(font= ('Helvetica', 7 ,'bold', 'italic'), width= 30,fg= "yellow", bg="blue")
```

I need to set the default tab width to be wider to accomodate the tab names. I cannot access the tab width property. The last line I tried using `.configure(width=30)`, this had no effect on the tab!

Answer (score 2):

OK , I have got the solution , although ugly. It does manipulate tab widths.

```
class TextBookGUI:


# class constructor
# populates each note book page
def __init__(self, master):

    #place hash tables here

    """
     Create 5 pages on using Pmw notebook widget.
     Documenation for notebook:
     http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/NoteBook.html
    """
    Pmw.initialise(master)
    self.nb = Pmw.NoteBook(master,borderwidth=2,arrownavigation=True,tabpos='n')



    self.HomeTab = self.nb.add("Welcome")
    self.nb.tab('Welcome').focus_set()
    self.StudentTab = self.nb.add("Students")
    self.BookTab = self.nb.add("Books")
    self.LoanTab = self.nb.add("Loans")
    self.HelpTab = self.nb.add("Help")

    *self.nb._pageAttrs['Welcome']['tabreqwidth'] = 200
    self.nb._pageAttrs["Welcome"]['tabreqheight'] = 100
    self.nb._pageAttrs["Students"]['tabreqwidth'] = 200
    self.nb._pageAttrs["Students"]['tabreqheight'] = 100

    self.nb._pageAttrs["Books"]['tabreqwidth'] = 200
    self.nb._pageAttrs["Books"]['tabreqheight'] = 100

    self.nb._pageAttrs['Loans']['tabreqwidth'] = 200
    self.nb._pageAttrs["Loans"]['tabreqheight'] = 100

    self.nb._pageAttrs['Help']['tabreqwidth'] = 200
    self.nb._pageAttrs["Help"]['tabreqheight'] = 100*


    #format the house style of tabs: yellow bg and blue text   
    self.nb.component('Welcome-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                        fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)

    self.nb.component('Students-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                        fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)

    self.nb.component('Books-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                        fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)
    self.nb.component('Loans-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                        fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)

    self.nb.component('Help-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20,'bold italic'),
                        fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)

    self.nb.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    self.nb.setnaturalsize()
```

Having searched the net ,someone suggested iterating the page attribute dictionary with iterrkeys(). This  did not work so I took the code out of  the  loop and used  the attributes from the pageAttrs dictionary, which were were [reqtabwidth], [reqtabheight]. It worked!The code has stars around it and was added to the code above.You can see the text size is now 20 and it displays in a nice large tab.That is two evenings wasted for such a simple task.

Comment: Well found!  That was more time than I had available to dig. :)

Comment: I have found out where I went wrong initially: Pmw has three kinds of notebook according to the book by Grayson called "Python and Tkinter programming"- notebook, notebookR and notebookS. This has since been replaced by NoteBook but there is backwards compatibility .I should have just used a notebookS page(62) which has tabwidth property that can be set in the initialise() method!

Answer (score -1):

Annoyingly, while you've correctly set the tab width within the widget (I can see it using `cget('width')`, the megawidget doesn't appear to honor the width setting.

However, it does resize each tab to ensure that it's wide enough to correctly display the text.  If you're not seeing the full text of each tab, it may be because the root window isn't sized wide enough to allow the full width to be displayed.  Try adding a forced size (e.g., `root.geometry('500x200')`) and see if that helps.

I'd love to have a better answer for you, but that's the best I can do.  Good luck!